# Why am I getting duplicated query records in Oracle 12c database?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I'm doing data extraction and I'm new with Oracle databases, I was given a query by some sort of expert in these matters, but after reviewing the data I exported in a CSV I noticed that there was duplicated data, specifically one record, the query is this one:

```
SELECT 
  1 AS SourceID,
  to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as CreatedDateTime
  ,'PAN' AS Customer_Code
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Trim(tibom010.t$mitm), CHR(13), ' '), CHR(10), ' ') , CHR(9), ' ')  AS TopLevelPartNumber
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Trim(itm.t$dsca), CHR(13), ' '), CHR(10), ' ') , CHR(9), ' ')  AS TopLevelPartNumberDescription
  ,tibom010.t$pono AS BOMPositionNumber
  ,tibom010.t$seqn AS BOMSequence
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Trim(tibom010.t$sitm), CHR(13), ' '), CHR(10), ' ') , CHR(9), ' ')  AS ComponentPartNumber
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Trim(itm2.t$dsca), CHR(13), ' '), CHR(10), ' ') , CHR(9), ' ')  AS ComponentPartDescription
  ,tibom010.t$qana AS QuanityPer
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Trim(itm2.t$cuni), CHR(13), ' '), CHR(10), ' ') , CHR(9), ' ')  AS UnitOfMeasure
  ,to_char(New_Time(tibom010.t$indt,'GMT','PDT'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS EffectiveDate
  ,CASE WHEN (tibom010.t$exdt > to_date('01/01/1970','mm/dd/yyyy')) THEN to_char(New_Time(tibom010.t$exdt,'GMT','PDT'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') ELSE NULL END AS ExpirationDate
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Trim(rf.t$lcid), CHR(13), ' '), CHR(10), ' ') , CHR(9), ' ')  AS ReferenceDesignatorLocation
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Trim(rf.t$qana), CHR(13), ' '), CHR(10), ' ') , CHR(9), ' ')  AS ReferenceDesignatorLocationQuantity
FROM baan.ttibom010335 tibom010
  LEFT OUTER JOIN baan.ttcibd001335 itm ON (itm.t$item = tibom010.t$mitm)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN baan.ttcibd001335 itm2 ON (itm2.t$item = tibom010.t$sitm)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN baan.ttibom020335 rf ON (rf.t$mitm = tibom010.t$mitm AND rf.t$pono = tibom010.t$pono AND rf.t$seqn = tibom010.t$seqn)
start WITH trim(tibom010.t$mitm) LIKE 'PNW%'
connect BY prior tibom010.t$sitm = tibom010.t$mitm;
```

I found the duplicated data when running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM baan.ttibom010335 tibom010 where trim(tibom010.t$mitm) = 'PNW-710-000162' and trim(tibom010.t$sitm) = 'PNW-510-000060' AND tibom010.t$seqn = 2;
```

The query from above returns only one item, however the extraction found 5.
Does it have something to do with the start function or any of the other native functions from the Oracle Database? if so, which one?

Comment: May we ask why you aren't going back to the folks who gave you this query?  I mean, it's their code, and they should take responsibility for it (I think).  It would be hard for anyone here to debug this without seeing sample data to make this a reproducible problem.

Comment: I think your issue is probably that your `START WITH` clause expects the hierarchy root parents to start with `PNW%` - so children should NOT start with PNW. But you found a child record which DOES start with PNW, so the query's expectations don't match the data.

Comment: Try this query to find other duplicates: `select * from baan.ttibom010335 where trim(t$sitm) like 'PNW%'`

Comment: @kfinity That could be the problem, what would you recommend to do with the ```START WITH``` clause?